# lua basic how to loop?

Tags: lua, autotouch

hi I'm kinda new in this scripting im trying to make automation script from macro app ios/android that using lua language called autotouch https://autotouch.net/server/doc/en.html#autotouch-document
i'm clueless where to start from scratch is there lua function like this? 
searching for color in whole screen then tap it
the script is similar to this

```
loop
color = PixelSearch(x coord, y coord, #somergbColor codes)
If (color) is found in screen then
    tap it

else
   tap teleport skill/walk to search for target button 

endif
endloop

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop isn't too specific. You could do the inner actions in two 2 ways using [`findColor(color, count, region)`](https://autotouch.net/server/doc/en.html#findcolorcolor-count-region) provided by AutoTouch, or [`getColor(x, y)`](https://autotouch.net/server/doc/en.html#getcolorx-y) (essentialy faster in octet-size than [`getColors(locations)`](http://autotouch.net/server/doc/en.html#getcolorslocations) in my opinion, because of the return's value; but the problem is from the developers if they don't put a byte array API for handling lower and unsigned integers, of course).

`findColor()` is being limited to only find 1 pixel at max..

```
local target = 0x447111;
local location = findColor(target, 1);
local first = location[1];

if location and first then
    touchDown(1, first[1], first[2]);
else
    -- I don't understand this action?
end
```

So, if you want to find your color manually you can use `getColor()`.

```
local target = 0x447111;
local w, h = getScreenResolution();

local broken = false;

for y = 1, h do
    for x = 1, w do
        local cur = getColor(x, y);
        if cur == target then
            broken = true;
            break;
        end
    end
    if broken then
        break;
    end
end

if broken then
    touchDown(1, 1, 1);
end
```